# Ionic Cordova Storage will result into a data-loss when building apk on a different machine

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, build, storage

Currently we are facing a weird Issue when building our Ionic Cordova App for Android. We use the IonicStorageModule to store local data for the user, configured as the following:

```
IonicStorageModule.forRoot({
      name: 'ourDbName',
      driverOrder: [CordovaSQLiteDriver._driver, 'indexeddb', 'websql', 'localstorage'],
    }),
```

Me and my coworker are both using the same Computers (M1 MacBook) with the same dev-enviroment installed. We face the following issue:

```
Apk 1 is build on PC1 and installed via PlayStore; 
Apk 2 is build on PC2 and user updated via PlayStore to that build;
```

Installing Apk2 results into a loss of all data that was saved with Apk1. The code in both builds is the same. Building and update the apk form the same PC is not resulting into a data-loss.

Maybe someone has an idea or can give a general understanding in how working with Android  could potentionally lead to a data-loss when building on different devices.